# How to fit a linear regression model with two principal components in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression, pca

Let's say I have a data matrix d

```
pc = prcomp(d)

# pc1 and pc2 are the principal components  
pc1 = pc$rotation[,1] 
pc2 = pc$rotation[,2]
```

Then this should fit the linear regression model right?

```
r = lm(y ~ pc1+pc2)
```

But then I get this error :

```
Errormodel.frame.default(formula = y ~ pc1+pc2, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
   unequal dimensions('pc1')
```

I guess there a packages out there who do this automatically, but this should work too?

Answer (score 18):

Answer: you don't want pc$rotation, it's the rotation matrix and not the matrix of rotated values (scores).

Make up some data:

```
x1 = runif(100)
x2 = runif(100)
y = rnorm(2+3*x1+4*x2)
d = cbind(x1,x2)

pc = prcomp(d)
dim(pc$rotation)
## [1] 2 2
```

Oops.  The "x" component is what we want.  From ?prcomp:

> x: if ‘retx’ is true the value of the rotated data (the centred (and scaled if requested) data multiplied by the ‘rotation' matrix) is returned.

```
dim(pc$x)
## [1] 100   2
lm(y~pc$x[,1]+pc$x[,2])
## 
## Call:
## lm(formula = y ~ pc$x[, 1] + pc$x[, 2])

## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)    pc$x[, 1]    pc$x[, 2]  
##     0.04942      0.14272     -0.13557
```

Comment: hey, this seems to work , but I tried this in R 
> pc
Standard deviations:
[1] 0.3068542 0.2650774

Rotation:
          PC1        PC2
x1 -0.5518651  0.8339334
x2 -0.8339334 -0.5518651

x1[1] is the first element of x1

> x1[1]
  [1] 0.69602246 

> x2[1]
  [1] 0.268991455 

Then the first element of pc$x[,1]  must be  the first element of the first pricipal component right ? 
So shouldnt pc$x[1,1] = pc$rotation[1,1]*x1[1]+pc$rotation[1,2]*x2[1] ? 

> pc$rotation[1,1]*x1[1]+pc$rotation[1,2]*x2[1]
[1] -0.1597895

but actually pc$x[1,1] is : 
> pc$x[1,1]
[1] 0.08993233

Comment: This looks terrible , isnt there a way to separate the lines ?